# How to make a Perl 6 script exit on Ctrl+D input?

Tags: raku

```perl6
loop {
  my $word = prompt '> ' ;
  say $word;
}
```

What's the right way to make it `exit` if/when instead of printing a word I press Ctrl+D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm less familiar with Perl 6 than with Perl 5, but the Perl 5 method seems to work:

```
loop {
  my $word = prompt '> ' ; 
  last if not defined $word;
  say $word;
}
```

This might be more idiomatic:

```
while (defined my $word = prompt '> ') {
    say $word;
}
```

(Without the `defined` operator, the loop will terminate on an empty input.)

Comment: Sure, `unless defined` is equivalent to `if not defined`, Personally, I find the `if not` form clearer.

Answer (score 5):

With a little helper sub:

```
sub not-done(\value) {
    value but True if value.defined
}
```

Then you can just write your loop as:

```
while not-done prompt("> ") -> $word {
    say $word
}
```